# YouTube Analytics API Error - You do not have permission to execute reports.query method

Tags: youtube-analytics, youtube-analytics-api

Getting Error You do not have permission to execute reports.query method in youtube Analytic? How to execute reports.query method in youtube Analytics?

I followed steps in the video but cant clear the error Video Link - [YouTube Developers Live: Troubleshooting the YouTube Analytics](http://APIyoutube.com/watch?v=wx1a1crkPEQ)

Comment: I followed steps in the video but cant clear the error                                               Video Link -  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wx1a1crkPEQ

Answer (score 0):

Google apis work on on basic premmis.  Data is either Public or Private.   Public data can be accessed by anyone.  Private data you must have permissions to access.

YouTube Analytics reports is private data you need to be authenticated in order to access it.  You will also need to have requested permissions with the following scope.

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly

There is more information here on how to set up access [Step 1: Retrieve authorization credentials](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reports/#step-1-retrieve-authorization-credentials)